# Android Progress Bar With Ballons

Tags: android, user-interface, view, progress-bar

Are there any Android Progress Bars like this:

[image]

If not, how can I do it?

I want to programmatically set balloons that will be rendered in the correct position over the progress bar, preferentially accepting a view to be rendered as a balloon.

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar

Comment: That's half the problem...but still there isn't an option to set the balloons, at least I didn't see.

Comment: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar  you can customise it

Comment: Well, if those are the only options, I guess I will have to customize them a lot.

Comment: wish you good luck thanks